# AirPlay without Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, airplay, television

Why are there AirPlay speakers or audio, but not for Video. I.e I have yet to see a single TV set support AirPlay mirroring, while many support Andriod ChromeCast type.

Is it possible to have Video AirPlay to TV set without Apple TV, if not, is it because Apple has yet to open up the protocol?

Answer (score 1):

"AirPlay speakers" are to be used when you have an Apple router that's directly connected to some speakers (no TV), therefore you can only stream audio and not video.

If you were to connect an Apple TV to a monitor, then you can stream both audio and video, as well as mirror your iPhone/MacBook screen onto your TV. Unfortunately, without an Apple TV you cannot stream video.